# Agent/actor like constructs in clojure that operate on all messages received since last update

Tags: clojure, actor, agents, core.async, pulsar

What's best way in clojure to implement something like an actor or agent (asynchronously updated, uncoordinated reference) that does the following?

- gets sent messages/data
- executes some function on that data to obtain new state; something like `(fn [state new-msgs] ...)`
- continues to receive messages/data during that update
- once done with that update, runs the same update function against *all* messages that have been sent in the interim

An agent doesn't seem quite right here. One must simultaneously `send` function and data to agents, which doesn't leave room for a function which operates on *all* data that has come in during the last update. The goal implicitly requires a decoupling of function and data.

The actor model seems generally better suited in that there is a decoupling of function and data. However, all actor frameworks I'm aware of seem to assume each message sent will be processed separately. It's not clear how one would turn this on it's head without adding extra machinery. I know [Pulsar's](http://docs.paralleluniverse.co/pulsar/) actors accept a `:lifecycle-handle` function which can be used to make actors do "special tricks" but there isn't a lot of documentation around this so it's unclear whether the functionality would be helpful.

I *do* have a solution to this problem using agents, `core.async` channels, and `watch` functions, but it's a bit messy, and I'm hoping there is a better solution. I'll post it as a solution in case others find it helpful, but I'd like to see what other's come up with.

Comment: "One must simultaneously send function and data to agents" -> only functions get sent to agents.

Comment: I disagree; you can send arguments to the agent along with the function. These arguments are data, yes?

Comment: @metasoarous It's equivalent to sending just functions. In fact the actual implementation is just a convenience to transform `(send a f x y)` into `(send a #(f % x y))` for you.

Comment: @amalloy - Fair enough. Nonetheless, it's still the case that you're sending data to the agent (through a closure).

Comment: I don't understand the need to run the update function over (a collection of?) all messages "in the interim". Are you saying that the update function takes too long to process? Or is there a potential interdependency of the messages that need to be processed?

Comment: Yes, the update function is a somewhat long running process. It is also a statistical function, and together with the current state of the agent/actor, can take as much data as is available to arrive at the new state. What's more, the compute time as a function of new data begins to settle down as the amount of already processed data increases. Thus, the system as a whole is more efficient if at every update, all of the available data is processed.

Comment: @metasoarous - you are not sending data to the agent, because regardless of the content of the agent, it does not have access to that data. Only the function you pass in is given the data you pass in.

Comment: @noisesmith - I would still interpret this as data being sent to the agent, even though the data is in a closure and not directly accessible to the agent.
Regardless of interpretation, it remains that **with respect to the problem statement** data and function are coupled, making the goal impossible with agents alone.
While I respect your position and find this side discussion interesting, I don't see it contributing to a solution of the problem.
If you'd like to continue debating, I suggest we do so in a Clojure Google group thread.

Comment: my pedantry here isn't pointless - `agents` are not a tool that is designed for the pattern of behavior you are describing, and the misconception that you could send data to an agent is, I believe, part of this misunderstanding

Comment: Where did I say that agents are the right tool for this pattern? I believe I said "An agent doesn't seem quite right here." I did say that I'm looking for something _like_ an agent, and I maintain that this is the case; both are asynchronously updated, uncoordinated references.

Comment: I've (hopefully) clarified the problem description some and more carefully qualified the described similarities to agents.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the solution I came up with using agents, core.async channels, and watch functions. Again, it's a bit messy, but it does what I need it to for now. Here it is, in broad strokes:

```
(require '[clojure.core.async :as async :refer [>!! <!! >! <! chan go]])

; We'll call this thing a queued-agent
(defprotocol IQueuedAgent
  (enqueue [this message])
  (ping [this]))

(defrecord QueuedAgent [agent queue]
  IQueuedAgent
  (enqueue [_ message]
    (go (>! queue message)))
  (ping [_]
    (send agent identity)))


; Need a function for draining a core async channel of all messages
(defn drain! [c]
  (let [cc (chan 1)]
    (go (>! cc ::queue-empty))
    (letfn
      ; This fn does all the hard work, but closes over cc to avoid reconstruction
      [(drainer! [c]
         (let [[v _] (<!! (go (async/alts! [c cc] :priority true)))]
           (if (= v ::queue-empty)
             (lazy-seq [])
             (lazy-seq (cons v (drainer! c))))))]
      (drainer! c))))

; Constructor function
(defn queued-agent [& {:keys [buffer update-fn init-fn error-handler-builder] :or {:buffer 100}}]
  (let [q                (chan buffer)
        a                (agent (if init-fn (init-fn) {}))
        error-handler-fn (error-handler-builder q a)]
    ; Set up the queue, and watcher which runs the update function when there is new data
    (add-watch
      a
      :update-conv
      (fn [k r o n]
        (let [queued (drain! q)]
          (when-not (empty? queued)
            (send a update-fn queued error-handler-fn)))))
    (QueuedAgent. a q)))

; Now we can use these like this

(def a (queued-agent
         :init-fn   (fn [] {:some "initial value"})
         :update-fn (fn [a queued-data error-handler-fn]
                      (println "Receiving data" queued-data)
                      ; Simulate some work/load on data
                      (Thread/sleep 2000)
                      (println "Done with work; ready to queue more up!"))
         ; This is a little warty at the moment, but closing over the queue and agent lets you requeue work on
         ; failure so you can try again.
         :error-handler-builder
                    (fn [q a] (println "do something with errors"))))

(defn -main []
  (doseq [i (range 10)]
    (enqueue a (str "data" i))
    (Thread/sleep 500) ; simulate things happening
    ; This part stinks... have to manually let the queued agent know that we've queued some things up for it
    (ping a)))
```

As you'll notice, having to ping the queued-agent here every time new data is added is pretty warty. It definitely feels like things are being twisted out of typical usage.

Answer (score 1):

Agents are the inverse of what you want here - they are a value that gets sent updating functions. This easiest with a queue and a Thread. For convenience I am using `future` to construct the thread.

```
user> (def q (java.util.concurrent.LinkedBlockingDeque.)) 
#'user/q
user> (defn accumulate
        [summary input]
        (let [{vowels true consonents false}
              (group-by #(contains? (set "aeiouAEIOU") %) input)]
          (-> summary
            (update-in [:vowels] + (count vowels))
            (update-in [:consonents] + (count consonents)))))
#'user/accumulate
user> (def worker
           (future (loop [summary {:vowels 0 :consonents 0} in-string (.take q)]
                         (if (not in-string)
                             summary
                           (recur (accumulate summary in-string)
                                  (.take q))))))
#'user/worker
user> (.add q "hello")
true
user> (.add q "goodbye")
true
user> (.add q false)
true
user> @worker
{:vowels 5, :consonents 7}
```

Comment: For all your pedantry, you missed one of the main points of the problem :-) Processing should occur automatically whenever there is new work to do. With your solution, processing can only occur once.

Comment: messages are consumed immediately, and processing occurs when every message is consumed, change the map to an atom that gets passed in to the loop if you want to access intermediate state (or add prints if you just want to verify the processing occured)

Answer (score 0):

I came up with something closer to an actor, inspired by Tim Baldridge's cast on actors (Episode 16). I think this addresses the problem much more cleanly.

```
(defmacro take-all! [c]
  `(loop [acc# []]
     (let [[v# ~c] (alts! [~c] :default nil)]
       (if (not= ~c :default)
         (recur (conj acc# v#))
         acc#))))


(defn eager-actor [f]
  (let [msgbox (chan 1024)]
    (go (loop [f f]
          (let [first-msg (<! msgbox) ; do this so we park efficiently, and only
                                      ; run when there are actually messages
                msgs      (take-all! msgbox)
                msgs      (concat [first-msg] msgs)]
            (recur (f msgs)))))
    msgbox))


(let [a (eager-actor (fn f [ms]
                       (Thread/sleep 1000) ; simulate work
                       (println "doing something with" ms)
                       f))]
  (doseq [i (range 20)]
    (Thread/sleep 300)
    (put! a i)))
;; =>
;; doing something with (0)
;; doing something with (1 2 3)
;; doing something with (4 5 6)
;; doing something with (7 8 9 10)
;; doing something with (11 12 13)
```